# Random Number Generation in least computation time

Tags: algorithm, random

Can someone suggest an algorithm to find a random number within say a limit 'n', that could be computed in least computation time?

Comment: Computation time is language-dependent.

Comment: Depends on the quality of pseudo random numbers you need.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/221/. Guaranteed to be `O(super-duper fast)`. Any compiler worth its salt would probably inline this too for omgwtfbbq the fastest.

Comment: LOL. Jason! I can just LOL. Need a serious answer, though.

Comment: http://dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/00000/2000/300/2318/2318.strip.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Complementary-Multiply-with-Carry random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry) has a long period and with comparatively simple update operations.  It strikes a nice balance between speed and quality.

To see some working code, there is a [Python recipe for CMC](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576707/).